# Write method to a class dynamically at runtime in scala and create a jar

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect, scala-compiler

I would like to understand is there a way to write a method to existing class at runtime and to create a jar dynamically in scala.

So far i tried to create a class dynamically and able to run it thru reflection, however the class is dynamic class which isnt generated.

```
val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val tb = ToolBox(mirror).mkToolBox() 

val function = q"def function(x: Int): Int = x + 2"
    val functionWrapper = "object FunctionWrapper { " + function + "}"
data.map(x => tb.eval(q"$functionSymbol.function($x)"))
```

i got this from other source, however the class is available only for this run and will not be generated.

i would like to add a function to the existing class at runtime and able to compile it and create a jar for it.

Kindly suggest me the way

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need this? Are you sure this is the only, or the best, solution your problem?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez we will receive a string, based on it we need to add this as method to the class at runtime and need to generate a jar. so i started to first create a dynamic class, but not able to generate here. however i need to add the function to existing class.

Comment: Why do you need to receive arbitrary code as a **String**? Are you aware that this approach is very insecure. As well as unsafe from a type perspective and the overall process will be slow. - Again, I ask, what is the outer problem that lead to this design, there should be alternatives.

Comment: We might actually receive an expression, based on the expression we need to create it a method for further use for spark udf creation.

Comment: So what could these expressions look like? It's usually better to come up with a restrictive language that allows users to express exactly what is needed and no more. This expression can then be compiled into a function object using a technique known as partial evaluation.

Comment: This will be my last comment and I won't insist more since you came here wanting help not to be told what to do but. Who are the ones writing those udfs? Someone with a programming background, if so why not juts programming and deploying new jars? Someone without programming back ground, so maybe you should just write a small parser for a simple grammar and instead of compiling classes and growing bigger a jar, you could save those on some db and access them by some id. Also, it may be good to give a look to **Apache Zeppelin**.

Comment: Someone with programming background will use the udf once the udfs are available. i would like to understand on how can we generate a class and bind it with jar dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the code snippet you provided should actually look like

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val tb = ToolBox(mirror).mkToolBox()

val function: Tree = q"def function(x: Int): Int = x + 2"
val functionWrapper: Symbol = tb.define(q"object FunctionWrapper { $function }".asInstanceOf[ImplDef])
val data: List[Tree] = List(q"1", q"2")
data.map(x => tb.eval(q"$functionWrapper.function($x)")) // List(3, 4)
```

> ... however the class is dynamic class which **isnt generated.**
>
> ... however the class is available only for this run and **will not be generated.**

How did you check that the class is not generated? (Which class, `FunctionWrapper`?)

> is there a way to write a method to existing class at runtime and to create a jar dynamically in scala.
>
> i would like to add a function to the existing class at runtime and able to compile it and create a jar for it.

What is "existing class"? Do you have access to its sources? Then you can modify the sources, compile them etc.

Does the class exist as a `.class` file? You can modify its byte code with [Byte-buddy](https://bytebuddy.net), [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/), [Javassist](https://www.javassist.org/), [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) etc., instrument the byte code with [aspects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) etc.

Is it dynamic class (like `FunctionWrapper` above)? How did you create it? (For `FunctionWrapper` you have access to its `Symbol` so you can use it in further sources.)

Is the class already *loaded*? Then you'll have to play with class loaders (unload, modify, load modified).

[Can a Java class add a method to itself at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680674/can-a-java-class-add-a-method-to-itself-at-runtime)

[In Java, given an object, is it possible to override one of the methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631361/in-java-given-an-object-is-it-possible-to-override-one-of-the-methods)

Comment: Thanks for the info Dmytro..
1. Yes, FunctionWrapper class isnt generated.
2. ok, will take a look on Byte-buddy

Comment: @user3569397 In what sense `FunctionWrapper` isn't generated? You have its symbol, you can use it in further sources. How do you check that it's not generated? What are you trying to do with `FunctionWrapper` that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @user3569397 If you create toolbox with `ToolBox(mirror).mkToolBox(options = "-d /path/to/dir")` then in `dir` you'll find `.class` file for `FunctionWrapper`. Without `-d` option it was created in a virtual directory in memory.

Comment: Hi Dmytro, apologies if am not explaining it correctly. i tried checking in source packages.  May i please request you where can i check the class created?

Comment: @user3569397 It's not in `src/main/scala...`, it's in `dir` that you specify with `-d` key in `options` parameter of `mkToolBox`, otherwise it's in memory (by default). https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/ToolBoxFactory.scala#L46-L50

Comment: @user3569397 The directory must exist in a disc.

Comment: Thanks Dmytro, will take a look and will try few things with Byte-buddy as well. i might need help in classloaders .

Comment: @user3569397 Inside `dir` object `FunctionWrapper` is generated in a package with random name `__wrapper$1$92c082bff0fc4ea08f1579a2633c937c`. If you want to have this name in your code you can do `tb.eval(q"$functionWrapper.getClass.getName")` and this will give `__wrapper$1$f3d3f4d7a84347dd8f979d628f85d93e.FunctionWrapper$`.